# Setting MacOS target version for Bazel build

Tags: macos, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build the TensorFlow Lite C library on MacOS 11.4. I need the built library to be able to run on MacOS 10.13 or newer. However, something in the build toolchain sets the target OS to 11.3, so that the full compile commands printed by `-s` look like this

```
(cd /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ojs/8ce6bb5f0f6d53a52ea9c48238c2c3a8/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    APPLE_SDK_PLATFORM=MacOSX \
    APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE=11.3 \
    PATH=/Users/ojs/Library/Caches/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-3.7.2-darwin-x86_64/bin:/Users/ojs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/ojs/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools \
    TF2_BEHAVIOR=1 \
    XCODE_VERSION_OVERRIDE=12.5.0.12E262 \
  external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1' '-std=c++11' -iquote external/ruy -iquote bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/ruy -iquote external/cpuinfo -iquote bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/cpuinfo -iquote external/clog -iquote bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/clog -Ibazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/cpuinfo/_virtual_includes/cpuinfo -Ibazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/clog/_virtual_includes/clog -MD -MF bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/ruy/ruy/_objs/frontend/frontend.d '-DCLOG_VISIBILITY=' '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/ruy/ruy/_objs/frontend/frontend.o' -isysroot __BAZEL_XCODE_SDKROOT__ -F__BAZEL_XCODE_SDKROOT__/System/Library/Frameworks -F__BAZEL_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR__/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks '-mmacosx-version-min=11.3' -DGRPC_BAZEL_BUILD -w -mavx '-std=c++14' -Wall -Wextra -Wc++14-compat -Wundef -O3 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c external/ruy/ruy/frontend.cc -o bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/external/ruy/ruy/_objs/frontend/frontend.o)
```

Using `--copt='-mmacosx-version-min=10.13'` on command line produces compiler commands with both `'-mmacosx-version-min=11.3'` and `'-mmacosx-version-min=10.13'` in argument list, and the resulting binary seems to have higher requirement. Setting `APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE` either as environment variable or using `--action_env` does not change the value that shows up in build log. I can't find any instances of `APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE` in the project's bazel build files. How do I set the target platform?

Comment: Have you tried to run bazel with `APPLE_SDK_VERSION_OVERRIDE=10.3 bazel build`?

Comment: @Slay yes, that's the "as environment variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that works is Bazel command line option `--macos_minimum_os` (or related `--macos_minimum_os`).

It's right there in the documentation if you know what to search for, but apparently not discoverable by Google. I found it by reading Bazel source.